# google cloud shell open browser inside shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

is it possible to open the browser inside gcp cloud shell, or alternatively is it possible to have a desktop access to the cloud shell through the browser ?  I am trying to run istio inside cloud shell, which I have done successfully.  However to view the sample application I need to open a browser inside the cloudshell itself.  I am not sure how to do it from my browser on my laptop and what uri I should use.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

It depends on your "client" for Cloud Shell.

If you're using the browser, there's a menu option that permits publishing a Cloud Shell port (this used to be a limited set of ports e.g. `8080` but I think it's now broader).

[image]

If you're using `gcloud`, you can use the following command  to port-forward the Cloud Shell instance's `CLDS_PORT` to your host's `HOST_PORT`:

```sh
gcloud cloud-shell ssh --ssh-flag="-L [HOST_PORT]:localhost:[CLDS_PORT]"
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately either of them does not work.  preview port only lets you include port numbers, and I cannot ssh from my desktop to gcloud shell due to company restrictions.  Basically I'm trying to access an url like http://192.168.49.2:31541/productpage from my gcloud instance.  I'm trying to run istio sample on the gcloud shell.

Comment: Using the browser Cloud Shell, you can publish a port from a service running on the Cloud Shell instance and then Web Preview on the port (e.g. 31541) and browse it. You don't use a `192.168.xxx.yyy` address but let Cloud Shell open the page for you using a `*.cloudshell dev` host.

Comment: See [Using Web Preview](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/using-web-preview)